# measure of $|\alpha-\frac pq|\lt\frac1{4q^2}$ with infinitely solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

$\alpha\in[0,1]$, and
$$|\alpha-\frac pq|\lt\frac1{4q^2}$$
has infinitely solutions $p, q\in\Bbb Z$,  $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Let $E$ be the set of all such $\alpha\in[0,1]$, that is

$$E=\{\alpha\in[0,1]\colon |\alpha-\frac pq|\lt\frac1{4q^2} \text{ has infinitely solutions}\;   p, q\in\Bbb Z,  \gcd(p,q)=1\}$$

What is the measure of $E$?

---

Of course, $E\ne [0,1]$; some irrationals don't belong to $E$.
I don't know how to move on.

Generally, we can consider  $$E_r=\{\alpha\in[0,1]\colon |\alpha-\frac pq|\lt\frac1{rq^2} \text{ has infinitely solutions}\;   p, q\in\Bbb Z,  \gcd(p,q)=1\}$$
for $r\gt\sqrt5$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the source of the problem?

Comment: No source. I am thinking about the dense of $\{n^2\alpha\}$, and  propose the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Khinchin](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486696308.html)

The integers $a_k$ are called the elements, with the possible exception of $a_0$ they are positive. Here we go, on page 7 we find his numbering,
$$  q_{k+1} = a_{k+1} q_k +  q_{k-1}.  $$ On page 9 we have Theorem 9, 
$$    \left| \alpha - \frac{p_k}{q_k} \right| < \frac{1}{q_k q_{k+1}}  <  \frac{1}{ a_{k+1} q_k^2}             $$
If the elements are unbounded, every time $a_{k+1} > r$ your inequality is satisfied.

Theorem 29, page 60: the set of all numbers in $(0,1)$ with bounded elements is of measure zero.

THEREFORE the set of all numbers in $(0,1)$ with an unbounded sequence of elements is of measure one.

Theorem 23, page 36: for every real number $\alpha$ with an unbounded sequence of elements and arbitrary $c > 0,$ there are infinitely many solutions to $$\left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{c}{q^2}    $$